# Symfony 5 custom 404 page

Tags: symfony, http-status-code-404, symfony5

I'm trying to create a custom 404 page for a Symfony 5 project that must:

1. Output a simple JSON-encoded string, like "Not found".

   - Said string must be read from a translation resource.
2. Have an additional `Content-Type: application/json` header.

There is a section in the Symfony docs, [that attempts to explain how this can be achieved](https://symfony.com/doc/current/controller/error_pages.html#overriding-the-default-errorcontroller), but the information seems incomplete/incorrect, apparently being written for the 4.X version, even pointing to non-existent source files on GitHub.

I have managed to create an error controller, but it swallows all errors:

```yaml
# config/packages/framework.yaml
framework:
    error_controller: App\Controller\ErrorController::errorHandler
```

```php
// src/Controller/ErrorController.php
class ErrorController extends AbstractController
{
    public function errorHandler(TranslatorInterface $translator) : JsonResponse
    {
        return new JsonResponse($translator->trans('not_found'));
    }
}
```

The problem is that this results in any error (including internal ones) returning a 404 page.

How can I make this controller/method handle only 404 errors and leave everything else to be handled as before by the framework itself?

Comment: You're right about the docs being out of date, afaict. *However* is that the only thing you tried? It literally says: "To override non-HTML error output, the Serializer component needs to be installed." (have you done that?). if your page already uses the default `_format` json (meaning, everything is json api) that might already do most of your work. So read up on the section Overriding error output for non-html formats: https://symfony.com/doc/current/controller/error_pages.html#overriding-error-output-for-non-html-formats come back, if problems persist....

Comment: also as a feasible alternative, you could also implement an EventListener that listens to the kernel.exception event, to be specific to the notfound exception (don't know the exact name, I believe it's `HttpNotFoundException`) and generate a `Response` and set it on the event, which should immediately stop propagation of that event and return whatever response you have. EventListeners can also be injected with the TranslatorInterface, so it's almost no difference to your controller, but is more specific to the 404

Answer (score 5):

**For anyone else that is looking for a solution to a JSON 404 page for a Symfony application:**

I was looking for a way to use a controller to handle specific error cases as it seemed the easiest option on the surface, but this does not seem to be possible, or at least I have not figured out how.

In the end, I reached a solution using [events and event listeners](https://symfony.com/doc/current/event_dispatcher.html):

Configuration:

```yaml
# config/services.yaml

services:

    ...

    # This listener handles only 404 errors in PROD mode
    App\EventListener\ExceptionListener:
        tags:
            - { name: kernel.event_listener, event: kernel.exception }
```

Event listener:

```php
// src/EventListener/ExceptionListener.php
class ExceptionListener {
    public function onKernelException(ExceptionEvent $event) : void
    {
        if (
            $_ENV['APP_ENV'] != 'prod'
            || !$event->isMasterRequest()
            || !$event->getThrowable() instanceof NotFoundHttpException
        ) {
            return;
        }

        // Send a not found in JSON format
        $event->setResponse(new JsonResponse($this->translator->trans('not_found')));
    }
}
```